# Может ли бот Telegram посылать оповещения при определённых событиях?

Tags: telegram-bot

Хочу создать Бота, который будет посылать оповещения о выключении света в офисе или об отключении сервера. Перерыл кучу сайтов  и так не понял, есть ли такая возможность у бота или нет? Сделал,чтобы он отвечал на вопросы без проблем, а вот чтобы он сам при определенном событии присылал оповещения не могу.
Если есть,то какой командой регулируется это в апи?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

То, что Вам нужно - это обычный **POST/GET** запрос вида

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<YourBotToken>/sendMessage?chat_id=1234567&text=HelloBot
```

где:

- `<YourBotToken>` - токен Вашего бота;
- `chat_id` - идентификатор того чата, куда вы хотите послать сообщение;
- `text` - текст самого сообщения.

Вешаете на нужное событие этот запрос, передавая соответствующие `chat_id` и `text`, получаете профит.

---

**Важно** понимать, что если бот заблокирован пользователем (попросту говоря - удалён), то запрос вернёт ошибку и пользователь сообщение не получит. При этом если у бота не реализована обработка исключений, то он упадёт.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что такой бот будет исключительно публичный?

Comment: Не понял вопроса. Что значит "публичный бот"?

Comment: Значит что на этот бот сможет подписаться кто угодно. А хотелось бы сделать личную уведомлялку без лишних глаз и не писать при этом полноценного бота.

Comment: Для этого есть Telegram API, а боты не бывают приватными. Для простых уведомлений бота писать не нужно, вообще. Достаточно создать его и использовать токен в запросах, подобных тому, что показан в ответе.

Comment: Что касается того, кто подпишется или нет на бота - имеет значение только в том случае, если будет реализована массовая рассылка. Пример выше показывает, как послать уведомление одному конкретному пользователю, кроме него это сообщение никто не получит

Comment: "То, что Вам нужно - это обычный POST/GET запрос вида" А как этот запрос исполнить из программы?

Comment: @ПавелГлазков это базовая возможность любого языка программирования/фреймворка