# Уведомления с сайта в Telegram

Tags: php, веб-программирование, telegram-bot, telegram, уведомления

Есть сайт, созданный без использования движков. Хочу прикрутить форму обратной связи, чтобы посетитель оставил свой номер и имя в специальной форме, а эти данные потом передались менеджеру в Telegram. Можете подробно объяснить, как это делается?

Comment: возможный дубликат - [Может ли бот Telegram посылать оповещения при определённых событиях?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545045/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82-telegram-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Попробуйте сервис https://formfor.site/. Отлично подходит для этих целей

Comment: Или просто попробовать такой сервис как https://www.telenote.site

Answer (score 25):

1. Создаешь нового бота в Telegram, пишешь сюда: t.me/botFather сначала /start, затем /newbot.
2. Узнаешь ID твоего аккаунта в Telegram. Сделать это можно, написав боту t.me/userinfobot
3. Создаешь ссылку на API Telegram для отправки сообщения в чат с тобой (предварительно нужно начать чат с твоим ботом в Telegram, для этого нужно нажать /start). Ссылка выглядит таким образом: 
   `https://api.telegram.org/bot[Токен бота]/sendMessage?chat_id=[Твой ID]&text=[Текст]`
4. Затем нужно настроить обработчик твоей формы. Тут уже по твоей части, просто берем данные, к примеру:

   ```
   $phone = $_POST['phone'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
   ```
5. Затем генерируем сообщение, которое хотим отправить в Telegram. Опять же, для примера:

   ```
   $msg = "Новая заявка на сайте! \nE-mail: $email \nТелефон: $phone \n Имя: 
   $name";
   ```
6. Затем необходимо отправить эти данные в телеграм. Делать это можно разными способами, самый простой:

   ```
   $token = *Вставь сюда токен своего бота*;
   $telegram_admin_id = *Сюда твой ID, взятый из userinfobot*;
   $msg = "Новая заявка на сайте! \nE-mail: $email \nТелефон: $phone \n 
   Имя: $name";
   file_get_contents(https://api.telegram.org/bot'. $token .'/sendMessage?
   chat_id='. $telegram_admin_id .'&text=' . urlencode($msg));
   ```

Comment: А если необходимо делать рассылку всем, кто подписан на данного бота. Как быть?

Comment: @Batyabest сохранять в БД всех пользователей, кто подписан на бота. Т.е. каждый раз при сообщении от пользователя проверять, есть ли данный пользователь в БД. Рассылку можно будет сделать через обычный цикл.

Comment: а как собирать тех, кто подписан на бота? Есть какая та стандартная команда для этого?

Comment: @Batyabest погрузитесь немного в документацию API telegram'a. Увидите, что каждое сообщение в себе несет ID юзера. А дальше - делайте с ним то, что пожелаете нужным. Хоть в текстовых файлах храните через `;`, хоть в БД. Стандартной команды, кто УЖЕ подписан - нет. Можно только собирать по сообщениям.