# Уведомления с сайта в telegramm

Tags: php, telegram, push

Использую `onesignal` для **уведомлений** через сайт.

Скажите, есть ли способ интегрировать их в `телеграмм`?

И как это сделать? Не нашел ничего похожего.

Comment: @ShevtsovEugene уведомление которое я отправляю через web должно так-же отправляться в telegram канал

Answer (score 2):

https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/api#making-requests

-_-

Документация api, на русском языке!

Comment: Я так понял что создаешь бота и с сайта общаешься с ним, а он делает сообщения в телеге

Comment: Как то сложно, то есть делать бота - прослойку, и код бота будет больше чем код самого проекта...

Comment: смотри что нашел))) https://begtin.tech/feedbot/

Comment: Это хороший бот, но он для RSS лент, как я понял, но никак нельзя связать именно Push уведомление и телеграмм канал?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/688794