# В Telegram из макроса VBA Excel?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, vba, telegram

Подскажите пожалуйста есть форма в Excele (для  записи заявок на сервис), очень много чего завязано на telegram. Заинтересовал вот  подобный  вариант отправки сообщения.

Вот код (не мой), тут просто отправка текста латиницей. Короче понимаю, что тут все просто для тех кто шарит, но я еще только осваиваю. Прошу помочь.

Задача: отправка текста с определенных ячеек Excel по кнопке.

```
Sub Send_to_Telegram_Bot_example() 
Dim oHttp As Object
Dim sURI As String

'token = "00000000:AaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAa"
'chat_id = "88888888"
'txt = "hello"

'sURI = "https://api.telegram.org/bot000000000:Aa....AaAa/getme"
'sURI = "https://api.telegram.org/bot000000000:Aa....AaAa/getupdates"

'sendproto не работает!!! Блин, не знаю, как скормить строке имя файла С:\temp\pic.png?
'запрос с файлом должен быть в формате multipart/form-data
'sURI = "https://api.telegram.org/bot000000000:Aa.....AaAa/sendproto?chat_id=88888888@photo=C:\temp\pic.png"

sURI = "https://api.telegram.org/bot000000000:Aa....AaAa/sendmessage?chat_id=88888888&text=hello"

MsgBox sURI, vbInformation, "запрос"
On Error Resume Next
Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest")
End If
On Error GoTo 0
If oHttp Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
oHttp.Open "GET", sURI, False
oHttp.Send
MsgBox oHttp.ResponseText, vbInformation, "ответ"
Set oHttp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Так, а в чем проблема то? Пишете обработчик на клик, выбираете из Excel нужные данные и дёргаете API `sendmessage`..

Comment: Я паялник ,  только недавно коснулся темы подобной , и ночи стали бессонными ) но тут я чесно нехрена не понимаю (пардон) можно пожалуйста пример маленький .)) Благодарен буду .

Comment: у вас там `sendProto`

Comment: а вообще фото так не отправляется (с указанием локального местоположения)

Comment: Да спасибо , фото не важны ,основная проблема как с определённой ячейки или группы ячеек проварить по кнопке

Comment: связано - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/547648/183842

Comment: *фото не важны* - а что, у вас и с отправкой текста проблемы? в чём конкретно проблема?

Comment: Конкретно проблема в том что не могу сообразить как отправка с определенных ячеек происходят , и как сказать ," бери текст в этой ячейки потом в этой и т. д , добавь вот этот текс и отправь

Comment: так это вопрос не к телеграму а к экселю

Comment: по какой логике предполагается выбирать ячейки?

Comment: Есть шаблон отправки , фио ,телефон , заявленная проблема ,заказчик , исполнитель. Это не изменяемые позиции. Заполняет мастер эти пункты и отправляет по нажатию на кнопку